# How to exclude some elements from xPath?

Tags: xpath

The HTML is something like this:

```
1...   <div>
2...      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 1</div>
3...      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 2</div>
4...   </div>
5...   <div>
6...      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 3</div>
7...       <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 4</div>
8...  </div>
9...  <div>
10..      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 5</div>
11..      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 6</div>
12..  </div>
13..  <div>
14..      <div><span class="some-class"></span>"&nbsp "</div>
15..      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 8</div>
16..  </div>
17..  <div>
18..      <div><span class="some-class"></span>&nbsp</div>
19..      <div><span class="some-class"></span>Text 10</div>
20..  </div>
```

I need to choose all elements with "some-class" except two elements on line 14 and 18 with xPath

```
//span[@class = 'some-class']  --  This one return 10 elements
```

I tried:

```
//span[@class='some-class'][not(text()=' ')]  --  As a value for text() tried "&nbsp" also
```

Not worked. Is it possible to choose just 8 elements and exclude 2 with xPath?

Comment: In your example, the text is not actually inside the span elements.  Are you really trying to select the span elements or are you trying to select *div* elements containing span elements with "some-class" and not containing "empty" text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method
/root/*[not(self::a)]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really want to select the span elements (as in your example) and not the div elements that actually contain the sample text and assuming that you meant true `&nbsp;` entities (your example does not have the semi-colon) and assuming that your intention is to skip those spans where the div text is effectively empty (any combination of spaces, double-quotes, and `&nbsp;` entites then you can try something like:

```
//span[@class="some-class" and not(string-length(translate(../text(), '&#160; "', ''))=0)]
```

The ../text() selects the text of the immediate parent of the span.  The `&#160` is the entity code for the nbsp.  The translate() function is effectively converting the three characters mentioned to nothing so we can test to see if there is anything else in the text.

However, you may run into challenges with the `&nbsp;` and `&#160;` entity references depending on the DOCTYPE of your input or how you are invoking the XPath evaluation.  You may be able to just use `&nbsp;` in the XPath expression instead of the `&#160` equivalent.

The example expression I provided above results in eight spans.  Using your input they are indistinguishable:

```
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
<span class="some-class"/>
```

Let's tweak your input a little bit to better see the results:

```
 <div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 1</span>Text 1</div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 2</span>Text 2</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 3</span>Text 3</div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 4</span>Text 4</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 5</span>Text 5</div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 6</span>Text 6</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 7</span>"&nbsp; "</div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 8</span>Text 8</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 9</span>&nbsp;</div>
    <div><span class="some-class">span 10</span>Text 10</div>
</div>
```

The expression selects:

```
<span class="some-class">span 1</span>
<span class="some-class">span 2</span>
<span class="some-class">span 3</span>
<span class="some-class">span 4</span>
<span class="some-class">span 5</span>
<span class="some-class">span 6</span>
<span class="some-class">span 8</span>
<span class="some-class">span 10</span>
```

Comment: I apologize. The text wrapped with span not div. Actually, I am writing an automation script to assert table column names. I handled this by looping through indexes, and pass empty spans. Thank you